# API doesn't receive file + text posted through a FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, ionic4

I want to upload an file with a text to my api. The Api says that the schema is not JSON but multipart. So I included the information(image and text) in a FormData in order to post it to the api afterwards.
This looks like this:

My class model:

```
export class FormData {
    image: any;
    category: string;

   constructor(args){
      this.image = args.image;
      this.category = args.category;
   }
  }
```

api call:

```
apiSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData(this.categoryForm.value);
  console.log(formData);

  this.http.post<any>(this.url, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(
    (res) => console.log(res),
  );
}
```

The values are actually assigned to formData, so FormData has both values the file and the text stored.

[image: FormData log]But somehow the data doesn't find its was to the api properly:( when I want to post, the api spits out the following error.

[image]

Do I somehow have to singely show the api which part of the FormData is the file and which part is the string? And if yes how would I do that?

Comment: @CherryDT well actually when I change it to `File`it doesn't throw a new error. Its all the same. How could I do that in my code with the await thing you've mentioned. I don't really see where to change something.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe work. You must send a Blob type.

In this example I'll send a base64 file, this is a better option.

```
export class FileData {
    contentBase64: string;
    mimeType: string;
    name: string;
}

apiSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const blob = new Blob([file.contentBase64], { type: file.mimeType });
  formData.append('file', blob, file.name);

  this.http.post<any>(this.url, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(
    (res) => console.log(res),
  );
}
```